# Change in Menu of Admin Panel in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to move menu in another menu.
For example in this image in menu(admin Panel), I want to move `MagentoGarden` into `ProductContact`.
How can I do this?
Any suggestions please or any site reference in which I can get answer for this query.[image]

Comment: MagentoGarden & ProductContact both are custom module menu?

Comment: Yes Sir @Abdul;

Comment: can share config.xml /adminhtml.xml code both module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find below code in both module may be in config.xml or in adminhtml.xml of your module located in etc folder

```
   <menu>
      <productContact module="productContact">
        <title>ProductContact</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <test module="ProductContact">
            <title>Manage ProductContact</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>your-admin-link</action>
          </test>
        </children>
      </productContact>
    </menu>
```

copy above code add in your **MagentoGarden** module

```
      <menu>
          <productContact module="productContact">
            <title>ProductContact</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
            <!--change below code with MagentoGarden code-->
              <magentoGarden module="MagentoGarden ">
                <title>Manage MagentoGarden </title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>your-admin-link</action>
              </magentoGarden >
            <!--change below code with MagentoGarden code-->
            </children>
          </productContact>
        </menu>
```

Comment: Its done . Thank u So Much. @Prashant Valanda